# Is sucking thumbs unhealthy?

Tags: medical-science

It is "common" knowledge that sucking your thumb (for little kids) is a "bad habit.

Is there any truth to this, and is it just a bad *habit* or actually unhealthy for you?

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what "bad" means in this context? The more specific you are, the more specific and detailed the answers you will get will be.

Comment: I am not sure what I mean by bad, for example, eating cake is good for you as it gives you energy, but it is bad if consumed excessively(perhaps makes you fat-which may be "bad" or increases your cholesterol). In any case, the "bad" I am using is as general as it can possibly be.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If nothing else, thumb sucking can have a pretty negative impact on teeth.

[The American Dental Association](http://www.ada.org/2977.aspx?currentTab=1) says:

> After the permanent teeth come in, sucking may cause problems with the proper growth of the mouth and alignment of the teeth. It can also cause changes in the roof of the mouth. The intensity of the sucking is a factor that determines whether or not dental problems may result. If children rest their thumbs passively in their mouths, they are less likely to have difficulty than those who vigorously suck their thumbs. Some aggressive thumbsuckers may cause problems with their baby (primary) teeth. If you notice changes in your child’s primary teeth, consult your dentist.

Wikipedia has a [decently sourced article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thumb_sucking#Dental_problems) on the subject.

Answer (score 7):

It can have multiple negative effects, first of all it can cause your [teeth to be misaligned](http://www.ada.org/2977.aspx?currentTab=1), but using a dummy (or pacifier) can also have the same effect.

> After the permanent teeth come in,
>   sucking may cause problems with the
>   proper growth of the mouth and
>   alignment of the teeth. It can also
>   cause changes in the roof of the
>   mouth. The intensity of the sucking is
>   a factor that determines whether or
>   not dental problems may result. If
>   children rest their thumbs passively
>   in their mouths, they are less likely
>   to have difficulty than those who
>   vigorously suck their thumbs. Some
>   aggressive thumbsuckers may cause
>   problems with their baby (primary)
>   teeth. If you notice changes in your
>   child’s primary teeth, consult your
>   dentist.

It can also result in [tounge thrust that can result in speech problems](http://www.speechpathology.com/askexpert/display_question.asp?question_id=57).

> When of short duration, they typically
>   do not have a significant effect on
>   the development of the oral
>   musculature, the relationship of the
>   dentition and occlusion, or on speech
>   development and production. However,
>   such practices, if persistent across
>   many years may result in a
>   myofunctional condition. That is, the
>   muscles in the front of the mouth
>   (lips and surrounding area) are used,
>   while other muscles (e.g., the
>   masseter) are not as active. In
>   addition, a forward carriage of the
>   tongue may also exist at rest and
>   during swallowing. These factors in
>   combination may lead to a persistent
>   tongue thrust which can further
>   influence the oral muscle development,
>   occlusion, and alignment of teeth.

Finally there is some evidence that thumb sucking can in severe cases result in [digit deformity](http://jhs.sagepub.com/content/26/6/584.abstract).

> We report our experience with severe
>   digital deformities caused by
>   prolonged finger sucking. Our analysis
>   of nine patients demonstrated that the
>   deformity was mainly located in the
>   proximal and middle phalanges of the
>   affected digit(s). We have reviewed
>   the literature, enumerated the common
>   patterns of “finger sucking” and
>   explained the resulting deformities.
>   Corrective osteotomy, preferably at
>   the metacarpal base level, is required
>   in severe deformities.

It should be noted that all of the above are potential risks of consistent thumb sucking for an extended period of time, it is known that thumb sucking (or use of a pacifier) for a limited time can actually be a useful way for a small child to comfort themselves.  Basically if your younster does it now and again there is no need to freak out :).

There are some adults who like to suck thier thumb.  There is some fairly detailed information about it [here](http://www.thumbsuckingadults.com/mytsFAQpage.htm), but it appears to be based on personal experience.